# Using custom navigation service, how to pass a parameter to the next view model?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am coming up to speed on Xamarin. I am using "Mastering Xamarin.Forms: App architecture techniques for building multi-platform, native mobile apps with Xamarin.Forms 4, 3rd Edition" as a guide. This had me create a custom navigation service.

Here is the implementation (I skipped the interface for brevity)

```
namespace wfw_dispenser.Services
{
    public class XamarinFormsNavService : INavService
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Type, Type> _map = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler CanGoBackChanged;

        public INavigation XamarinFormsNav { get; set; }

        public bool CanGoBack => XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack?.Any() == true;

        public async Task GoBack()
        {
            if (CanGoBack)
            {
                await XamarinFormsNav.PopAsync(true);
                OnCanGoBackChanged();
            }
        }

        public async Task NavigateTo<TVM>()
            where TVM : BaseViewModel
        {
            await NavigateToView(typeof(TVM));

            if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel)
            {
                ((BaseViewModel)XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext).Init();
            }
        }

        public async Task NavigateTo<TVM, TParameter>(TParameter parameter)
            where TVM : BaseViewModel
        {
            await NavigateToView(typeof(TVM));

            if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel<TParameter>)
            {
                ((BaseViewModel<TParameter>)XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext).Init(parameter);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveLastView()
        {
            if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Count< 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            var lastView = XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack[XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Count - 2];

            XamarinFormsNav.RemovePage(lastView);
        }

        public void ClearBackStack()
        {
            if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Count < 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                XamarinFormsNav.RemovePage(XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack[i]);
            }
        }

        public void NavigateToUri(Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid URI");
            }

            Device.OpenUri(uri);
        }

        async Task NavigateToView(Type viewModelType)
        {
            if (!_map.TryGetValue(viewModelType, out Type viewType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No view found in view mapping for " + viewModelType.FullName + ".");
            }

            // Use reflection to get the View's constructor and create an instance of the View
            var constructor = viewType.GetTypeInfo()
                                      .DeclaredConstructors
                                      .FirstOrDefault(dc => !dc.GetParameters().Any());
            var view = constructor.Invoke(null) as Page;
            var vm = ((App)Application.Current).Kernel.GetService(viewModelType);

            view.BindingContext = vm;
            await XamarinFormsNav.PushAsync(view, true);
        }

        public void RegisterViewMapping(Type viewModel, Type view)
        {
            _map.Add(viewModel, view);
        }

        void OnCanGoBackChanged() => CanGoBackChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanGoBack"));
    }
}
```

It appears to me that there is a NavigateTo that takes a parameter. I tried it and it kind of goes nowhere without any errors in the log. There's nothing in the text about this method to explain how to use it.

I probably have to do something in the "catching" view model for this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: see the `BaseViewModel<T>` - https://github.com/edsnider/mastering-xamarin.forms-book/blob/f30fa18a72b9da0021ba021d5ad935492f8992d1/Chapter9/TripLog/TripLog/ViewModels/BaseViewModel.cs#L42

Comment: @Jason, Ahh, missed that. So I just implement that method in my concrete class?

Comment: Also you can write your type-check shorter with pattern-matching: `if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel baseVM) { baseVM.Init(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must extend from the parameterized version of BaseViewModel. In your case, since you are passing in a `PaymentRequest`, this would be:

```
public class CheckoutViewModel : BaseViewModel<PaymentRequest>
```

Then `BaseViewModel<T>` has a virtual `Init` method that you can implement

```
public class BaseViewModel<TParameter> : BaseViewModel
{
    protected BaseViewModel(INavService navService, IAnalyticsService analyticsService)
        : base(navService, analyticsService)
    {
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        Init(default(TParameter));
    }

    public virtual void Init(TParameter parameter)
    {
    }
}
```